# Tests not appearing in Visual Studio test explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having issues setting up my tests. I have tried using a console c# file for my selenium tests which runs the test however it doesn't appear in the test explorer. When I create a unit test c# project it doesn't run or show up in the test explorer. What have done wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace SeleniumTests1
{
    [TestClass]
    class SeleniumTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));
            searchInput.SendKeys("Hello World");
            searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"));
            string actualvalue = searchInput.GetAttribute("value");

            Assert.AreEqual(actualvalue, "Hello World");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test methods should normally refer to the logic that they are testing in their naming convention e.g. testHelloWorldOnBing(), etc. Then each test class should be in a test project that can then be run separately.

Answer (score 13):

This may work.  I think your TestMethod needs to be `public` and non-static in order for it to appear in Test Explorer.

```
namespace SeleniumTests1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SeleniumTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Main()
        {
```

Comment: Every developer should google if does not find the solution on itself within 10 minutes, I lost 2hr trying to understand why, then googled and whala here is the solution. By default VS creates the files without public statement

Answer (score 1):

You're making a Main method the test method?
Make a separate test project, then reference the project you're testing and move your code to that instead e.g.

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyProjTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test{
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I create a console c# project. Within that project I create a new c# test project I then reference the main method to the test? Sorry if I sound dumb.

Comment: So you make your console application, and then in that solution you make another project that is a test project (right click solution > add > new project > tests> unit tests and then right click references inside that project and click solution from that window and you'll see the name of your console app, click that, add a using to that project from the top of the unit test class and you're ready to start your unit testing

Comment: When I say console app, im just referring to an example of something you may be testing, in your case it would be a reference to wherever the code you wish to test resides

Answer (score 1):

Although this one's a rather obvious and straightforward answer, but, looking at the code posted originally by Peter and my own silly mistake I realized that one more place where we can go wrong is by **not making our outer test class public** without which they would default to internal and the contained tests would not show up in the test explorer. So, the final form of a unit test code would begin with something like this

```
namespace SeleniumTests1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class SeleniumTest
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void testMethod(string[] args)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have managed to resolve the issue in this instance by importing the 4 dlls from the net40 file from the selenium website.